# AVPlayerItem: Segment exceeds specified bandwidth

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, avplayeritem

I'm registering observer to AVPlayerItemNewErrorLogEntry, and sometimes 
I get this error statusCode: -12318 Segment exceeds specified bandwidth for variant when playing live hls. anybody know what causes this?

Thanks.

Comment: While I'm also looking for an official/better statement on this, I would assume that the segment uses too much bandwidth versus what has been specified... The video/audio would need to be compressed more, or the specifications would need to be adjusted up, etc.